# how meteor's restrictCreationByEmailDomain option work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteorite

i just read meteor's accounts config options, "restrictCreationByEmailDomain" option is awesome

```
Accounts.config({ restrictCreationByEmailDomain: 'school.edu' })
```

i want to know can i use a list of domains separated by comma or array in place of 'school.edu'
is there any simple tutorial for meteor accounts system ?
pls help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> restrictCreationByEmailDomain String Or **Function**
>
> If set, only allow new users with an email in the specified domain or if the **predicate function returns true**. Works with password-based sign-in and external services that expose email addresses (Google, Facebook, GitHub).

```
Accounts.config({
  restrictCreationByEmailDomain: function(email) {
    var domain = email.slice(email.lastIndexOf("@")+1); // or regex
    var allowed = ["school.edu", "school.edu.br"];
    return _.contains(allowed, domain);
  },
  ...
});
```

Comment: I don't know why you commented out the domain thing, that's kinda the way it was designed when we added this option